# Exponentiable 2-functors

Tags: ct.category-theory

The [exponentiable morphisms](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponentiable+morphism) in the category Cat are the [Giraud-Conduche functors](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Conduch%C3%A9+functor), which satisfy a "lifting of factorizations" property that is unique up to zigzags.

What are the exponentiable morphisms in the category 2-Cat?  Presumably they are some 2-categorical generalization of Giraud-Conduche functors with lifting of factorizations for both 1- and 2-cells; but has anyone written it down?  For definiteness, let's say the question is about exponentiability in the 1-category of strict 2-categories and strict 2-functors, but I'd be interested in answers for other flavors of 2-Cat as well.